# gcc error when installing python-axolotl module

Tags: python, c++, gcc

I am trying to install yowsup2. Some dependency modules install okay but getting trouble when trying to install python-axolotl module. It keeps bringing error: command 'c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1 error. I downloaded the source module files for python-axolotl and tried manual installation but still getting the same error. There was also a 'undefined reference to '_head_C_build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a' error

[image: Error in command lind]